# Passing value to child component after it's added to the list on parent component - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6, angular2-template

I'm working on small Angular project,  and I want to pass value from parent to child after it is addedd to the list, so it goes like this:

`new-component` emits item to `the list-component`

and after it's addedd to the list, lets move it forward to `view-component`, so I can see recently addedd item in case I want to edit something--

And everything works fine until I want to see it on `view-component` (it's successfully added to the list etc.) here is my code:

on a new component item is emitted to list:

```
onSubmit() {
    this._viewService.save(this.view)
      .subscribe(
        (data: View) => {
          this.onSave.emit(data);
        }
  }
```

As list is parent list is listening for this emitter.

```
<view-new #addNew (onSave)="onAdd($event)"></view-new>
```

After it is emitted, its available in `onAdd` method, and until this part everything is ok:

```
onAdd(view: View) {
    this.receivedView = view;
    // And here I'm opening viewDisplay compnent which displaying info about recently addedd data
    this.viewDisplay.show();
}
```

Also on my list which is parent component is also included display component, which needs to display info about recently addedd item:

```
  <view-display #displayView [view]="receivedView"></view-display>
```

And when I open this component by calling `this.viewDisplay.show();`

```
@Input() view: View;
```

Which is part of display component is allwayas empty :

```
show() {
    $('#' + this.id).modal('show');
    console.log("added - selected:view", this.view);
  }
```

`this.view` which should be filled onAdd method from parent and passed here is allways empty.. I dont know how..

Thanks guys

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Angular needs to know that the value of view has changed. You usually do this by defining a [setter](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter). By defining a setter, changes to an input variable can be tracked. You also need to define a private property to save the value in.

```
private _view: any;

@Input()
get view(): any) {
    return this._view;
}
set view(view: any) {
  this._view= view;
  // Do other stuff when "view" was updated
}
```

You can also handle the communiation via [the service pattern](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).

Comment: if I set value this.receivedView = view;, and when I call that child component shouldn't it look for the value in this.receivedView and simply read it

Comment: It depends on Angulars change detection mechanism. If you do stuff after change detection ran, then Angular won't be notified of the change. I also updated my answer for an additional way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

you are updating field `recievedView` in a parent, which is bound to `view` field in a child. This binding is done by angular change detection mechanism. In your onAdd method you are trying to call `viewDisplay.show()` method synchroniously, before the change detection is done, and, because of this field is not updated yet. The simplest solution would be to assign the field of a child in place like

```
onAdd(view: View) {
  this.receivedView = this.viewDisplay = view;
  this.viewDisplay.show();
}
```

but there are surely better options which depend on your project